# WeChat app keeps auto-opening on phone unlock

Tags: lock-screens, virus, wechat

Since this morning, whenever I open and unlock my phone, it buzzes quickly upon unlock and opens the Wechat app, even though I have force closed it and cleared the cache. I have also restarted my phone and tried turning off notifications. Neither has changed the issue.

I'm on a Samsung Galaxy S20, have not installed any new apps to my knowledge since this behavior started happening. Googling the issue, a lot of folks mentioned a virus through a blank app causing similar behavior, but I was unable to find it. I ran Kaspersky and it didn't detect a virus.

Is this an app setting, a Wechat issue or do I have a virus?

Answer (score 2):

Just figured it out myself but if you have a wallet phone and a chip card, the NFC is what's triggering wechat to come up. Try turning off NFC and see if it helps.